# How to arrange RadioGroup buttons in box form Check Code

Tags: android, xml

I want my button to align themselves in a box form where one aligns on top of the other i have tried with the vertical but it destroys my entire shape. My Xml code. I know i can achieve this when each radio button is independent but it wont perform the work of a radio button. Any help will be appreciated. 
This is what i have [image]

```
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/radioGroup"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingTop="25sp"
        android:paddingBottom="45sp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/start_button"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="75dp">

        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="90dp"
            android:layout_height="90dp"
            android:id="@+id/subtract"
            android:text="−"

            android:shadowColor="#f99e0c"
            android:shadowDx="0"
            android:shadowDy="0"
            android:shadowRadius="10"
            android:textColor = "#F000"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textSize="65sp"
            android:background="@drawable/backcolor1"
            android:button="@null"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/radioGroup"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/settings"
            android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/settings" />

        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="90dp"
            android:layout_height="90dp"
            android:id="@+id/add"
            android:background="@drawable/backcolor1"
            android:text="+"
            android:shadowColor="#f99e0c"
            android:shadowDx="0"
            android:shadowDy="0"
            android:shadowRadius="10"
            android:textColor = "#F000"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textSize="65sp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:button="@null"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/multiply"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/divide"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/divide" />

        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="90dp"
            android:layout_height="90dp"
            android:id="@+id/divide"

            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="÷"

            android:shadowColor="#f99e0c"
            android:shadowDx="0"
            android:shadowDy="0"
            android:shadowRadius="10"
            android:textColor = "#F000"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textSize="65sp"
            android:background="@drawable/backcolor1"
            android:button="@null"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_below="@+id/radioGroup"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/settings"
            android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/settings" />

        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="90dp"
            android:layout_height="90dp"

            android:gravity="center"

            android:background="@drawable/backcolor1"
            android:id="@+id/multiply"
            android:text="∗"
            android:shadowColor="#f99e0c"
            android:shadowDx="0"
            android:shadowDy="0"
            android:shadowRadius="10"
            android:textColor = "#F000"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textSize="65sp"
            android:button="@null"
            android:layout_below="@+id/radioGroup"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/start_button"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/start_button" />

    </RadioGroup>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to update the radiobox programmly, normally, I do the radio function without system provided radiobutton, but by the `checkbox` with selector background, when I choose one of the item, I will update all of the checkboxes to unselected state state, then set the clicked item to selected state. looks it inefficiency, but, it's always work fine as far as I know.

eg.
like following code is doing after the item is clicked.

```
for (int i = 0; i < payItemList.size(); i++) {
   PayItem tmpItem = payItemList.get(i);
   tmpItem.setSelected(false);
}
payItem.setSelected(!payItem.isChecked());
```

PayItem

```
public class PayItem extends LinearLayout {
    @InjectView(R.id.callsys_impay_pay_icon)
    protected ImageView mIconImgView;
    @InjectView(R.id.callsys_impay_subject)
    protected TextView mSubjectTv;
    @InjectView(R.id.callsys_impay_pay_body)
    protected TextView mBodyTv;
    @InjectView(R.id.minesys_pay_chkbox)
    protected CheckBox mCheckBox;
    private Context context;

    public PayItem(Context context) {
        super(context);
        this.context = context;
        init();
    }

    public PayItem(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        this.context = context;
        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        View convertView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.kw_callsys_pay_item, this);
        ButterKnife.inject(this, convertView);
    }

    public void setEnable(boolean enable) {
        mSubjectTv.setTextColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.font_02));
        if (!enable) {
            mSubjectTv.setTextColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.font_gray));
        }
    }

    public boolean isChecked() {
        return mCheckBox.isChecked();
    }

    public void setSelected(boolean selected) {
        mCheckBox.setChecked(selected);
    }

    public void setContent(String icon, String subject, String body, boolean choosen) {
        int width = JApplication.getJContext().dip2px(48);
        KaowoImageLoader.loadImg(mIconImgView, icon, width, width, R.drawable.default_image);
        mSubjectTv.setText(subject);
        mBodyTv.setText(body);
        mCheckBox.setChecked(choosen);
    }

    public void setEnableSelectedClick(boolean enable) {
        setEnable(enable);
        setSelected(enable);
        setClickable(enable);
    }
}
```